# Were units of area/volume always in terms of squares/cubes?

Tags: geometry, units, ancient-egypt

Throughout our known history of geometry were the units representing areas and volumes always in terms of squares and cubes respectively? Take ancient Egyptian formulas as an example, the fact that their formulas are very close to ours must mean that the units representing areas and volumes were also unit squares and unit cubes, correct? I mean we can safely stamp their formulas with for example $cm$ and $cm^2$ and get the same result. And does that mean we can safely assume that they didn't measure e.g. volume by counting the number of times you can fill up an object by throwing identical fistfuls of sand into it?

Comment: In e.g. Euclidean geometry there were no "units of measure"

Comment: See e.g. [Early modern English area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_units#Area)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From your link take **rood** for example. What I am saying is we can't take our modern rectangle formula (length $*$ width) and get a correct answer in roods because a rood is a rectangular unit of measure, not a square.

Comment: Exactly; there were no cm in Ancient Egypt etc. And thus there were no "length sqaured" but area.

Comment: No. It was often more useful to tie volumes to weights (liter) or standard containers (amphora), and area to agricultural labor (carucate) than to length, see [List of obsolete units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obsolete_units_of_measurement). We are still using liters and gallons. And measuring volume by using sand or water to fill it up is actually quite effective.

Comment: @Conifold - Indeed, one could argue that the definition of a liter is the volume of a kilogram of water (which works out and is not a random occurrence).